# pyqt+maya = fatal error when click to context menu

Tags: pyqt, contextmenu, maya

i use pyqt in autodesk maya. all work but when i try connect a context menu to my elements - maya get fatal error and closed.

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om

import sip
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def getMayaWindow():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
form_class, base_class = uic.loadUiType('X:/tools/Maya/windows/2014/python/UI/perforceBrowserWnd.ui')

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# main window class
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class PerforceWindow(base_class, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):
        super(base_class, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Popup Menu is not visible, but we add actions from above
        self.popMenu = QtGui.QMenu( self )
        self.popMenu.addAction("revert", self.on_action_revert)
        self.popMenu.addAction("submit", self.on_action_submit)

        self.filesListWgt.customContextMenuRequested.connect( self.filesListWgtMenuRequested )

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    def filesListWgtMenuRequested(self, pos):
        self.popMenu.exec_( self.filesListWgt.mapToGlobal(pos) )

    def on_action_revert(self):
        print('on_action_revert')

    def on_action_submit(self):
        print('on_action_submit')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# window
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def perforceBrowser2():    
    perforceBrowserWnd = PerforceWindow()
    perforceBrowserWnd.show()

perforceBrowser2()
```

dialog created in qtdesigner. i set attribute contentMenuPolicy in designer on QListWidtet. when i right click on QListWidtet or any element - i see a context menu. but if i click a menu or dismiss it - maya get fatal error 
[image]

and i see log text - function on_action_revert is called. but after that - maya crashed.

what i doing wrong?

**update:**

i try simple test. replace a menu to simple call a function:

replace connect to:

```
    self.filesListWgt.customContextMenuRequested.connect( self.on_action_revert )

def on_action_revert(self):
    print('on_action_revert')
```

this crash maya too

Comment: What version of Maya are you testing on?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are choosing to use pyqt over pyside that ships with maya 2014?

Comment: opportunities pyqt above. including the fact that I can make a window in qtdesigner. plus to it I always use then these windows made on pyqt, and not only in maya. not a question of choosing pyside or pyqt. but how to make it work properly as I should (

Comment: I will look into the problem, but just a side note: we can use PySide as a complete replacement of PyQt, and is recommended to do so in Maya 2014+. You can continue to use Qt designed for that too.  Maya 2014+ ships natively with PySide; We need to make sure there are no build issues with your PyQt for Maya. That need not be done if you did it in PySide. Take a look at this article: http://www.jason-parks.com/artoftech/?p=579

Comment: Take a look at this. You can use this to write code that is compatible in both PyQt and PySide. https://github.com/rgalanakis/practicalmayapython/blob/master/src/chapter5/qtshim.py

Comment: you do not understand. I have a lot of software has been written under the pyqt and I just need to add to the finished application context menu. I'm not going to rewrite a lot of things just for the sake of adding menu. easier not to use the menu than move to other windows

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Your previous comment wasn't very clear.

Comment: i try simple test. replace a menu to simple call a function:

self.filesListWgt.customContextMenuRequested.connect( self.on_action_revert )

def on_action_revert(self):

 print('on_action_revert')

this crash maya too

Comment: Can I get your ui file so I can try testing on my end

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/0zAvZkeddbAtR

Comment: Ok, so your code works perfectly without crashing. I tested it on Maya 2013 and 2014

Comment: This is very strange. I have half a day trying different options and all lead to a crash. and I have seen the crash of the times and in other places when i connect some signals.

Comment: Your code is fine. I am pretty sure your code is not creating any issue. I have a feeling it is your PyQt build for Maya 2014.

Comment: P.s. You don't have to change any of your code to run on PySide FYI. I ran your code using PySide (with a qtshim) on Maya 2014 and it ran absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code along with your UI file on PyQt in Maya 2013 as well as on PySide (using a QtShim) on Maya 2014 and your code ran **fine**. **Please check your PyQt build for Maya 2014.**

I recommend attempting to run your code using PySide on Maya 2014. To do this you **do not need to change any of your code base**. You just need to modify a few imports. It is worth checking out these: Take a look at this. You can use this to write code that is compatible in both PyQt and PySide. https://github.com/rgalanakis/practicalmayapython/blob/master/src/chapter5/qtshim.py

And to load your ui file in PySide environment take a look at this article: http://www.jason-parks.com/artoftech/?p=579

PyQt and PySide are both *just python wrappers* for the Qt framework. They are identical apart from a very few differences. So your code base never needs to change no matter what you use to run it in.

P.s. But for whatever reason you are so particular for using PyQt for 2014,  Please use these guides to build it: http://download.autodesk.com/us/support/files/maya_documentation/pyqtmaya2014.pdf and this one: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2013/04/building-sip-and-pyqt-for-maya-2014.html

Comment: I try compile new version of PyQt + Sip. And cant do it. I dont know whats wrong, but its get to many error and not worked... maybe you can archive and send your kit pyqt +sip for maya 2014? I have windows 7 x64

Comment: At the studio we have Maya 2013, 2014 and 2015. We only have PyQt built for Maya 2013 since it doesn't make sense for us to do build PyQt for 2014 and 2015 as they have PySide. We use the concepts outlined in my answer to make our PyQt code run in all versions of Maya.

Comment: Quoting the official guide for building PyQt for Maya 2014: "However, be aware that with Maya 2014, there is no more need to build PySide as it is coming by default in Maya, nor you have to rebuild Qt itself as the main Qt tools to build PyAt are now included in the Maya distributions (I.e. qmake, moc, ) "

Comment: But for whatever reason you are so particular for using PyQt for 2014 (I honestly dont see why!) Please use these guides to build it: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=bGSdVMW_KoeyyQTQgYGYAw&url=http://download.autodesk.com/us/support/files/maya_documentation/pyqtmaya2014.pdf&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFBMjG9Rthwrei00KVHRSeJVHjggw&sig2=37J7_u0Komg3dfqu0aWwTw and this one: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2013/04/building-sip-and-pyqt-for-maya-2014.html all the best to you.

Comment: I reinstall all pyqt and sip. And all worked. Thanks! )

Comment: Great glad it worked out. Nice design btw. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Maya specific PyQt builds are maintained in this Github repo maintained by Marcus Ottosson. You can grab the specific build for yourself and add it to PYTHONPATH. I had the same issue in Maya 2015 and this helped.

https://github.com/pyqt

Comment: sorry, but problem was solved tho years ago ) and now i use maya 2017+ pyside )

Comment: @maxku: I have added the answer for reference to lot of people who are still on older version of maya.